# Plot matrix with hover label in Shiny

Tags: r, matrix, plot, shiny

I am plotting a matrix of DNA characters in shiny using the plot.matrix package which allows plotting of non-numeric matrix

I want to create the matrix plot in shiny and make it interactive, where when you hover over a sequence the name of the sequence appears.

e.g. in by below example the hover labels would be the row names R1, R2 etc,

Are there any good packages or ways to do this?

See below for an simplified example of my current code:

```
library(plot.matrix)
library(shiny)

matsample<- cbind(c("A","A","A","T"),c("A","A","A","T"),c("A","A","A","G"))
rownames(matsample) <- c("R1","R2","R3","R4")

ui <-  plotOutput("matimage")

server <- function(input, output){

output$matimage <- renderPlot({
        plot(matsample,col=rainbow(7),fmt.cell='%s',las=1, cex=0.5)},
        width=200,
        units='px')

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Would you consider a heatmap with plotly?

Comment: yes I would @Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `plotly` would be an option, you could use `heatmaply` like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(heatmaply)
alph <- c("A"=1, "C"=2, "G"=3, "T"=4, "I"=5, "U"=6, "N"=7)
seq <- factor(names(alph), unique(names(alph)))

# matsample <- cbind(c("A","A","A","T"),c("A","A","A","T"),c("A","A","A","G"))

matsample <- matrix(sample(names(alph), 4000, replace = TRUE), nrow=4)
ms <- matrix(alph[matsample], ncol = ncol(matsample), byrow=FALSE)
rownames(matsample) <- c("R1","R2","R3","R4")
rownames(ms) <- rownames(matsample)
mm <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(rownames(ms), rep, ncol(matsample))))
ui <-  plotlyOutput("matimage", width = 160 + (ncol(matsample)*20))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$matimage <- renderPlotly({
    heatmaply(ms, custom_hovertext = mm,
              cellnote = matsample,
              show_dendrogram = c(FALSE, FALSE),
              Rowv=NULL, Colv=NULL, color=rainbow(7),
              hide_colorbar=TRUE,
              plot_method = "plotly")
  })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't really understand what is represented in mm?- oh wait is it saying what label should be shown at each position of the sequence?

Comment: Yes, `mm` is the hover text matrix that contains the text that appears when you mouse over the respective field. In this case it is the row name.

Comment: so I tried this, and it works well with small data. However when my data contains sequences with around 600-1000 characters, its doesn't look so good. are there ways to make the actual plot wider/ scrollable rather than having to zoom in and out?

Comment: @hjf - Sure, just set a conditional plot width in your ui output. See edited reply.

Comment: that worked great! I was trying to adjust the width in the server which was why it wasn't going very well. thanks again